# AngularJS: get state name of the child from parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button in a parent state (let's call it "parentState") that should not be showed if the state children is named "childNthState". Is that possible to get the state name of the child from the parent, so i can put an ng-if in the template?

If not, what do you suggest as a solution?

Comment: The usual way to pass data from child to parent is to use `$emit` on the child scope, and catch it in the parent scope. Look at `$on` and `$emit` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: There are at least three options:  1.  `$emit` as @james00794 said (probably the best pattern).  2. Put the data on `$rootScope` which can be accessed anywhere.  3.  Put the data on a service that you inject into both controllers.

Comment: if u use ui-router this can be like <button ng-if="'childNthState' | includedByState">